# Change background of list elements

Tags: html, list, background

I'm just starting out learning HTML code. I don't know anything about CSS.  I've been messing around and created the following page.
[created web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELGgv.png)

Is there a way, using HTML code, to put a black background on the ordered list numbers and the unordered list pointers without it stretching the entire length of the screen?

Here is my current code.

```
 <body style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/luL5XM5.jpg');">
 

      <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size:45px; font-family:Lucida Handwriting; color:blue;">
         <span style="background: black;">️ <u>Careers in Engineering and Computer Science</u> ⌨️</span>
      </h1>

      <ol>
           <li style="font-size:35px; font-family:Algerian; color:red; margin-left:5%;">
              <span style="background: black;">D<small><small>atabase </small></small>A<small><small>dministrator</small></small></span>

                <ul style="font-size:20px; font-family:Showcard Gothic; color:green; list-style-type:'★  ';">

                     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ROepWrZ.gif" alt="Dog Driving Car" title="Dog Driving Car"
                        style="float:right; margin-right:80%; margin-top:5px; border:none; width="100"; height="75"; "/>

                     <li><span style="background: black;">Engineer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Programmer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Marketing</span></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <br>

           <li style="font-size:35px; font-family:Algerian; color:red; margin-left:5%;">
              <span style="background: black;">N<small><small>etwork </small></small>D<small><small>esigner</small></small></span>

                <ul style="font-size:20px; font-family:Showcard Gothic; color:green; list-style-type:'☛  ';">

                     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tjWSQXv.gif" alt="Dog on Computer" title="Dog on Computer"
                        style="float:right; margin-right:80%; margin-top:5px; border:none; width="100"; height="75"; "/>

                     <li><span style="background: black;">Engineer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Programmer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Marketing</span></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <br>

           <li style="font-size:35px; font-family:Algerian; color:red; margin-left:5%;">
              <span style="background: black;">S<small><small>oftware </small></small>E<small><small>ngineer</small></small></span>

                <ul style="font-size:20px; font-family:Showcard Gothic; color:green; list-style-type:'➺  ';">

                     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fYP4h9y.gif" alt="Dog Driving Car" title="Dog Driving Car"
                        style="float:right; margin-right:80%; margin-top:5px; border:none; width="100"; height="75"; "/>

                     <li><span style="background: black;">Engineer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Programmer</span></li>
                     <li><span style="background: black;">Marketing</span></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
      </ol>
      
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to fix that would be to add a width property to your style list. Example:
`<ul style="font-size:20px; font-family:Showcard Gothic; color:green; list-style-type:'☛  ';background-color:black;width:500px;">`

Comment: That works but that still adds more black background than I'm looking for. My ultimate goal is to just add a background to the numbers and pointers. I've figured out how to use span to add it behind the text but can't figure anything out for the numbers or pointers.

Comment: If I shrink the width down to cover just the pointers it messes with the image location.